# Fail to get longitude and latitude by GPS but succuss by network provider in Android?

Tags: android, gps

I can get longitude and latitude and convert them into geopoint when the device get location by network provider, but it fails when I am using gps. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (mLocation != null) {

            gp1 = getGeoByLocation(mLocation);
            gp2 = gp1;

            refreshMapView();

            if( !mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000,
                        10, mLocationListener);
            }else{
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000,
                                10, mLocationListener);
            }

    private GeoPoint getGeoByLocation(Location location) {
        GeoPoint gp = null;
        try {
            if (location != null) {
                double geoLatitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
                double geoLongitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;
                gp = new GeoPoint((int) geoLatitude, (int) geoLongitude);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return gp;
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem? what do you see in the logs?

Comment: Cannot display the string about longitude and latitude, also the image that point out my location when I am using gps;(

Answer (score 1):

`isProviderEnabled` will false if it is disabled in the Settings menu. If GPS is enabled you should see an icon on the notification/status bar.

Comment: Yes I can see a GPS icon on the notification/status bar, but cannot see a String about longitude and latitude on the screen. It success when I am using network provider to get location, but fail when using GPS.

Comment: How long did you wait?, Are you in an open area?  (It should be 10-15 minutes to get a fix and you should not me in a building)

Comment: About few minutes. The map can zoom into the area I am staying, but cannot display the longitude and latitude. I stay in a room now.

Comment: If the GPS icon is blinking it will take time to get the fix, You will know if there is a fix in the locationlistener.

Comment: Yes, but still cannot display the string about longitude and latitude, also the image that point out my location.

Answer (score 1):

GPS is much slower and often not available. If somebody is in a building, such as an office where software is developed or even a house/apartment of a software developer, then there is a good chance that you won't get a GPS fix. Our app relies heavily on location, and the bulk of the location coords we get are either from cell tower or wifi triangulation, both of which show up as NETWORK_PROVIDER.